# In Werewolv.es what offensive items does a protector protect against

Tags: werewolv.es

In werewolv.es the protector role is able to protect someone from being killed during the night, with the exception of attacks from specific roles.

There are also offensive items that can be used to kill/attack such as crossbow, war spear, poison darts etc.

What such items is the protector able to defend against and what go through?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are general rules of thumb for working out if the Protector's ability will stop an attack.

For attacks from a role's ability: Once per game abilities will generally bypass the Protector, although the Alphawolf's bonus kill is an exception to this. Roles with a repeatable kill will be protected against.

Items, even those with limited or one time uses are generally protected against. The exception to this is the Poison Darts item. This is less because of balance reasons but because of code implementation constraints. In the future, when the engine is expanded, the Protector may at some point prevent a death from poison.

In summary:

- Witch, Militia - bypass protection.
- Any wolf kill, or vampire attack - protected against.
- Single use item attack - protected against.
- Lasting poison effects - bypass protection.