# Poison Darts - can they be stopped? Are items stolen if they kill?

Tags: werewolv.es

Couple of question regarding certain interactions with poison darts.

Firstly, can the kill chance be protected from (either by roles or items)?

Secondly, if the kill part does happen, and the target had any items, who gets the items from that kill? Would it be the player who threw the dart, or the current holder of the poison darts (since they could have been passed along on a later night)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per this question - [what offensive items does a protector protect against](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/360529/in-werewolv-es-what-offensive-items-does-a-protector-protect-against) *currently* poison darts cannot be protected against by any item or role.

Secondly, if a player is killed by the poison, any items they are carrying will go to the grave with them, no 'tick' of a poison is not considered a visit from the attacker.